# Typescript for propert value of object of indefinite number of parameters

Tags: typescript

Let's say we have the variable

```
var Definitions = {
    "eat": "put (food) into the mouth and chew and swallow it",
    "drink": "take (a liquid) into the mouth and swallow.",
    "fly": "move through the air using wings."
}
```

I need to add type annotation for the `Definitions` variable to make sure each value is a string.

I tried things like:

```
var Definitions: {...string[]} = {
    "eat": "put (food) into the mouth and chew and swallow it",
    "drink": "take (a liquid) into the mouth and swallow.",
    "fly": "move through the air using wings."
}
```

and

```
var Definitions: {words:...string[]} = {
    "eat": "put (food) into the mouth and chew and swallow it",
    "drink": "take (a liquid) into the mouth and swallow.",
    "fly": "move through the air using wings."
}
```

But no luck

Comment: You can use `Definitions: Record<string,string> =` or if you want to limit the keys you can use `Record<"eat" | "drink" |"fly",string>`

Comment: Yes! that seems to work! Thank you so much! :) Can you please post this as an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
var Definitions: {
  [key: string]: string
} = {
    "eat": "put (food) into the mouth and chew and swallow it",
    "drink": "take (a liquid) into the mouth and swallow.",
    "fly": "move through the air using wings."
}
```